# Add a custom tick / marker for d3.time.scale() in a dc.js seriesChart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I would like to add a marker for a specific date for a date axis. Please see the line chart below.

My xAxis is drawn by this function, where dateMin and dateMax can be set by the user through the front end (or a brush, etc.).

```
d3.time.scale.utc().domain([dateMin,dateMax]);
```

This means the tickValues are calculated automatically.

Now, there is a certain fixed date for our data where there is a cutoff. For example, we may have consolidated figures up to Jan. 31st 2014, and then projected data from February 1st 2014 onwards.

What I need to do is make it visually clear at what date the cutoff point is. I have manually drawn a red vertical line at the date into the JPG below. But how do I do this programatically with d3?

One caveat is that the user might choose a date range (using the brush, etc.) which does not include the cutoff date (say, Jan 1st 2014 to Jan 20th, 2014). In this case, no line should be drawn.

If possible, it would be even better if the actual lines of the line chart would look different from the cutoff date onwards. They could be dotted instead of solid, or their colours could be less saturated (.brighter ?), to make visually clear that the underlying data is not consolidated yet.

Thanks for any hints you can give me.

Sorry I can't post images to StackOverflow yet, hence I uploaded the example here:

**Trying out code from the answers**

Using the code below, the line and label get drawn, but not at the given x value (cutoffDate), but too "early" on the time scale, approximately on the evening of 2014-01-29.

```
        var cutoffDate = new Date("2014-02-01T00:00:00Z");

        seriesChart.svg().append("svg:line")
                .attr("x1", xScale(cutoffDate))
                .attr("x2", xScale(cutoffDate))
                .attr("y1", yScale.range()[1])
                .attr("y2", yScale.range()[0])
                .style("stroke", "rgb(225,0,0)")
                .style("stroke-width", "1");

        seriesChart.svg()
                .append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("x", xScale(cutoffDate))
                .attr("y", 80)
                .text("Projected data");
```

See the result here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQBK.jpg

In my original question, I didn't mention I am using seriesChart from dc.js:
[seriesChart API docs](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#series-chart)
I suppose this does something with the xScale when it composes the seriesChart so setting a value on the xScale later on will result in a shifted display. Will investigate further.

**Update: x position fixed**

The correct way to append svg elements to a dc.js chart is not to use

```
chart.svg().append()
```

but

```
chart.chartBodyG().append()
```

This fixes the position offset for custom elements added to the chart. Using this in combination with Lars' answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be difficult to achieve with one axis, but easy with separate axes. First, for the dividing line, you can use code like this:

```
svg.append("line")
   .attr("x1", xScale(cutoffDate))
   .attr("x2", xScale(cutoffDate))
   .attr("y1", yScale.range()[0])
   .attr("y2", yScale.range()[1]);
svg.append("text").attr("x", xScale(cutoffDate) + 10).attr("y", yCoord)
   .text("projected");
```

To have different styles, use two different axes:

```
var xScale1 = d3.time.scale().domain([..., cutoffDate]).range([0, 100]),
    xScale2 = d3.time.scale().domain([cutoffDate, ...]).range([100, 200]);
svg.append("g").attr("class", "before")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale1));
svg.append("g").attr("class", "after")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale1.range()[1] + ",0)")
   .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale2));
```

Once appended, you can style the axes using the classes or by selecting the individual DOM elements. This means you end up with two scales -- to make using them for computing coordinates easier, you could wrap them:

```
var xScale = function(x) { return x < cutoffDate ? xScale1(x) : xScale2(x); };
```

The exact best way to implement this will depend on your specific application, but the above should give you a rough guide how to do it.

Comment: Lars, thank you for the code. For now I was able to test the line and text drawing code. It sort of works, but for some reason not at the right x (date) value. I suspect this has to do with the fact I am using the dc.js framework on top of d3 to draw a seriesChart (I want to use dc.js's crossfilter functions in this project.) I amended my question with an explanation.

Comment: My guess is that you need to add however much the chart region is offset to the value you get from the scale. It would help if you could post the code you're using.

Comment: You guessed right and led me on the right path. dc.js applies margins [link](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#margin-mixin). If I set these to 0 then the line is drawn at the correct x location. But I wonder how I can draw inside the given canvas including the margins without having to calculate them and putting magic numbers into my code.

Comment: You would need to append the line to the chart drawing area.

Comment: Thank you. I can read the left margin from the chart object and add it to the xScale of the line, and it works. I will report back on the second part about using two x axes tomorrow.